# Valgrind (memcheck) is not displaying the leak/error summary. Help?

Tags: centos, memory-leaks, valgrind, summary, memcheck

I typed in >>valgrind ./myprogramname --tools-memcheck --leak-check=yes

But the summary of the memory leaks and errors are not printing out when the program ends.  I am running Centos 5.5 and have even upgraded to the latest version of Valgrind to try and get this to work.  I have seen it print out a summary of problems before when I had the leak check option turn on.  Has anybody ever ran into this issue?

And I have even set --leak-check-full, among other things.  It is like Valgrind is not seeing my options that I am setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are placing the arguments for valgrind in a location where they will be interpreted as arguments to your program.

Try

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./myprogramname
```

and see if that works better.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I got it mixed up in my head.